# Define 2 SLA's in an assignment in pega

Tags: pega

Hi all i have a requirement, I have Two Work Objects(WO): WO-A and WO-B in work basket both of them are different types. I need to define sla for as soon as deadline is finished WO-A should be approved automatically and WO-B should notify manager. Both are in same assignment.

Comment: Could you please explain it ? I am not able to understand. What is `wos` and `wo` ?
If `wo` means work object then how come wo A and wo B are in same assignment ?

Comment: And any way there is no way you can add 2 SLA's on an assignment. Definitely there is a problem in understanding the requirement or the design is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One way of implementing this is using 1 SLA and create When rules to check the type of your Work Object and then conditionally do specifice actions. This can be done in either the Goal, Deadline or Post Deadline configurations of your SLA rule.  Check my example below in screenshot.

[image: SLA Example]